# Pytorch: Load a transformer model directly from torch checkpoint without loading pre-initialized weights

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I have a memory constraint while loading a model from a torch checkpoint for inference:
What I have is the following:

A torch model (xlm-roberta)
and a checkpoint (xlm-roberta-checkpoint.pth)

What normally happens is that we load the xlm-roberta as follows:

```
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('xlm-roberta-base')
checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
```

But the problem arises when loading the checkpoint; the pre-trained `model` itself is quite large, so both the checkpoint, and the model cannot fit in the memory and the process dies out.
Is there a way to directly load the checkpoint into the model class without initializing some random/pre-trained weights beforehand?